# Creating a custom distribution with specified skew and kurtosis

Tags: probability-or-statistics, random, distributions, finance

Let's say I want to create a simulated sample of returns for a given investing/trading strategy. I know that my strategy is profitable on 64% of trades, that the ratio of mean win / mean loss is 0.72, that the results are skewed negatively (skewness is -2.1) and fat tailed (excess kurtosis of 12.2). How can I model this distribution in *Mathematica* in order to sample it randomly?

I went into this problem thinking I could easily find a function like `SkewNormalDistribution`, except one that also had a kurtosis parameter. Would the `HyperbolicDistribution` function be the right choice here?

Comment: There are, of course, an infinite number of distributions that have the statistics you state.  You need to specify a *class* of distributions on which to set parameters.

Comment: From what data did you gain these parameters? Using that original data is probably more fruitful than using these derived parameters.

Comment: @Karsten7. Indeed this would be best. However, my hope is to be able to compare strategies that i have limited info about in a back-of-the-envelope type fashion. This data, for example, comes from a blog post:http://blog.factorwave.com/options-and-earnings

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I think that using `NormalDistribution` and/or the related modifications (`LogNormal`,`SkewNormal`, `TruncatedNormal`, etc) should provide a reasonable approximation for comparison. But perhaps a power law distribution such as `StudentTDistribution` or a Levy alpha-stable distribution would be a reasonable model also

Comment: You might want to check out the Pearson distribution system at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_distribution.

Comment: Did you try something yourself? With *Mathematica* it's relatively easy to exclude some of the distributions you are considering. For example `Skewness[LogNormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]]]` shows that there is no `LogNormalDistribution` with negative skewness.

Comment: A quick provisory try to find a `PearsonDistribution` that meets all parameters shows: 1) There is no `PearsonDistribution` that satisfies all parameters. 2) If one compromises one parameter (e.g., the ratio of mean win / mean loss, which presumably is the most uncertain one), there is one free parameter left to the `PearsonDistribution`.

Comment: @pyrex -- Could you please post an example of the data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

**Variant 1**

**define distribution_1 (losses)**

```
NSolve[Kurtosis[LogNormalDistribution[0, x]] == 12.2, x, Reals]
```

> {{x -> -0.579872}, {x -> 0.579872}}

```
LogNormalDistribution[0, 0.5798723392706395`] // Kurtosis
```

> 12.2

```
LogNormalDistribution[0, 0.5798723392706395`] // Skewness
```

> 2.14932

```
dist1 =
  TruncatedDistribution[
   {-\[Infinity], 0},
   SmoothKernelDistribution[
    -RandomVariate[LogNormalDistribution[0, 0.5798723392706395`], 10^6]
    ]
   ];
```

**define distribution_2 (winnings)**

```
LogNormalDistribution[0, 0.5798723392706395`] // Mean
```

> 1.18309

Mean of LogNormalDistribution = 1.18309. Win/loss should be 0.72.

```
Solve[x/1.1830856285552807` == 0.72, x]
```

> {{x->0.851822}}

```
NSolve[Mean@HalfNormalDistribution[x] == 0.8518216525598021`, x, Reals]
```

> {{x->1.17395}}

```
dist2 = HalfNormalDistribution[1.1739546617474543`];
```

**mix of distributions**

64% of trades are profitable

```
mix = MixtureDistribution[
   {0.36, 0.64},
   {dist1, dist2}
   ];
```

**EV = 0.1**

```
Mean@mix
```

> 0.118681

**Variant 2**

```
dist = EmpiricalDistribution[{0.36, 0.64} -> {-1, 0.72}];

Expectation[x, x \[Distributed] dist]
```

> 0.1008

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR:** There is no `PearsonDistribution` that matches all characteristics exactly, but there is an infinite number of `PearsonDistribution`s that resemble the given characteristics quite well. The difference between them is their standard deviation.

---

In my personal opinion the information given in the question and its foundation are insufficient to make any investment decisions. The subsequent answer to your question does not change this condition. (It's garbage, in garbage out.) In the following I'll restrain myself from making any further comments on the financial aspects of this question to stay on topic of this site and just explore how *Mathematica* can be used to find a distribution that matches the given limited information.

---

### 1. Excluding potential classes of distributions

In a [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114525/creating-a-custom-distribution-with-specified-skew-and-kurtosis#comment310634_114525) you mentioned the [`LogNormalDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogNormalDistribution.html) as one potential distribution. This distribution can easily be excluded from the list of distributions one might consider, as

```
Skewness[LogNormalDistribution[μ, σ]]
```

> `Sqrt[-1 + E^σ^2] (2 + E^σ^2)`

shows that it can't have a negative skewness. Other distributions can be excluded in a similar way.

Of course, one could consider

```
TransformedDistribution[-x, x \[Distributed] LogNormalDistribution[μ, σ]]
```

instead, but I won't go down the [derived statistical distributions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/DerivedDistributions.html) route.
One could also try to find a [nonparametric statistical distribution](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/NonparametricStatisticalDistributions.html) bases on the given characteristics in a similar way to [Finding Distribution based on quantile data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/98829/18476).

### 2. Finding a `PearsonDistribution`

As also suggested by [Jim Baldwin](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/19758/jim-baldwin) in a [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114525/creating-a-custom-distribution-with-specified-skew-and-kurtosis#comment310648_114525), I'll select the [`PearsonDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PearsonDistribution.html) as a potential distribution to meet the given criteria. The main reason for this choice is that it represents a broad [system of distributions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PearsonDistribution.html#1437778229).

The question I'll try to answer therefore becomes:
Is there a `PearsonDistribution` that meets all the criteria and if not, which one gives the "best" approximation?

I'll answer this question using an explorative approach. (In contrast to, e.g., a pure fitting approach.)

#### 2.1 Kurtosis & Skewness

```
kurtosis = Kurtosis[PearsonDistribution[a1, a0, b2, b1, b0]]

skewness = Skewness[PearsonDistribution[a1, a0, b2, b1, b0]]

sol1 = Solve[Simplify@skewness[[1, 1, 1]] == -2.1 && 
             Simplify@kurtosis[[1, 1, 1]] - 3 == 12.2, {a1, a0, b2, b1, b0}]
```

> ```
> {{a1 -> 7.25873 b2, b0 -> (0.0164534 a0^2 - 0.119431 a0 b1 + 0.466729 b1^2)/b2}}
> ```

```
{kurtosis[[1, 1, 2]], skewness[[1, 1, 2]]} /. sol1[[1]]
```

> `{True, True}`

All `PearsonDistribution`s with the given excess kurtosis of 12.2 and skewness of -2.1 are therefore defined by

```
pd[a0_, b1_, b2_] = PearsonDistribution[a1, a0, b2, b1, b0] /. sol1[[1]]
```

> ```
> PearsonDistribution[7.25873 b2, a0, b2, b1, 
>  (0.0164534 a0^2 - 0.119431 a0 b1 + 0.466729 b1^2)/b2]
> ```

#### 2.2 Percent profitable & mean win / mean loss ratio

The percent of profitable trades and the ratio of (mean win)/(mean loss) can now be written as

```
percentProfitable[a0_?NumericQ, b1_?NumericQ, b2_?NumericQ /; b2 != 0] := 
 NIntegrate[PDF[pd[a0, b1, b2], x], {x, 0, Infinity}]

meanWinLossRatio[a0_?NumericQ, b1_?NumericQ, b2_?NumericQ /; b2 != 0] := 
 (1 - 1/percentProfitable[a0, b1, b2])*
  NIntegrate[x*PDF[pd[a0, b1, b2], x], {x, 0, Infinity}]/
   NIntegrate[x*PDF[pd[a0, b1, b2], x], {x, -Infinity, 0}]
```

Using the following `Manipulate` demonstrates that only the sign of `b2`, but not its magnitude, has an influence on the percent profitable and (mean win)/(mean loss) ratio.

```
Manipulate[Column[{
   {percentProfitable[a0, b1, b2], meanWinLossRatio[a0, b1, b2]},
   Plot[PDF[pd[a0, b1, b2], x], {x, -100, 100}, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Medium]
   }],
 {{a0, 0.3912}, -2, 1}, {{b1, 0.338}, -1, 1}, {{b2, -0.01}, -0.1, 0.1, Appearance -> "Open"}]
```

[image: ManipulateAnimation]

Therefore I'll use a fixed `b2` arbitrarily set to `b2 = -0.01` for the next steps.
To see if there exists a pair of `a0` and `b1` that creates a `PearsonDistribution` for which `percentProfitable` is 0.64 and `meanWinLossRatio` is 0.72, [`ContourPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html) can be utilized.

```
With[{b2 = -0.01},
  ContourPlot[{percentProfitable[a0, b1, b2] == 0.64, 
      meanWinLossRatio[a0, b1, b2] == 0.72}, ##, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 300}] & @@@ 
   {{{a0, -2, 2}, {b1, -2, 2}}, {{a0, -0.01, 0.01}, {b1, -0.01, 0.01}}}] // Row
```

[image: ContourPlot]

Because there is no intersection between the two contours (they only come close to each other around `{0, 0}`), there is no `PearsonDistribution` that fulfills all criteria exactly. Graphically the situation can be explored further using

```
With[{b2 = -0.01},
 Plot3D[{percentProfitable[a0, b1, b2] == 0.64, 
   meanWinLossRatio[a0, b1, b2] == 0.72, 0}, {a0, -2, 2}, {b1, -2, 2},
   PlotRange -> {-0.2, 0.2}, ClippingStyle -> None, AxesLabel -> Automatic]]
```

[image: Plot3D]

Hence the question left is: What `PearsonDistribution` gives the "best" approximation.
Here I define "best" to be the one with the smallest total, equally weighted, relative deviation form the given parameters. One such distribution can be found using

```
With[{b2 = -0.01}, 
 NMinimize[(percentProfitable[a0, b1, b2] - 0.64)^2/0.64 + 
   (meanWinLossRatio[a0, b1, b2] - 0.72)^2/0.72, {a0, b1}]]
```

> `{0.000519924, {a0 -> 1.66369, b1 -> 1.50319}}`

Although [`NMinimize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMinimize.html) tries to find a global minimum, this is only a local one.

```
With[{b2 = -0.01},
 Plot3D[(percentProfitable[a0, b1, b2] - 0.64)^2/0.64 + 
  (meanWinLossRatio[a0, b1, b2] - 0.72)^2/0.72, {a0, 0, 2}, {b1, 0, 2}, 
  PlotRange -> {-0.01, 0.1}, ClippingStyle -> None, ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic]]
```

[image: MinErrorValley]

```
sample = With[{b2 = -0.01}, 
  Table[NMinimize[(percentProfitable[a0, b1, b2] - 0.64)^2/0.64 + 
    (meanWinLossRatio[a0, b1, b2] - 0.72)^2/0.72, b1], {a0, 0.1, 2, 0.1}]]
```

> ```
> {{0.000519924, {b1 -> 0.0903527}}, {0.000519924, {b1 -> 0.180705}}, 
>  {0.000519924, {b1 -> 0.271058}}, {0.000519924, {b1 -> 0.361411}}, 
>  {0.000519924, {b1 -> 0.451763}}, {0.000519924, {b1 -> 0.542116}}, 
>  {0.000519924, {b1 -> 0.632469}}, {0.000519924, {b1 -> 0.722821}}, 
>  {0.000519924, {b1 -> 0.813174}}, {0.000519924, {b1 -> 0.903527}}, 
>  {0.000519924, {b1 -> 0.993879}}, {0.000519924, {b1 -> 1.08423}}, 
>  {0.000519924, {b1 -> 1.17458}}, {0.000519924, {b1 -> 1.26494}}, 
>  {0.000519924, {b1 -> 1.35529}}, {0.000519924, {b1 -> 1.44564}}, 
>  {0.000519924, {b1 -> 1.536}}, {0.000519924, {b1 -> 1.62635}}, 
>  {0.000519924, {b1 -> 1.7167}}, {0.000519924, {b1 -> 1.80705}}}
> ```

```
approximationPoints = Transpose[{Table[a0, {a0, 0.1, 2, 0.1}], b1 /. sample[[All, 2]]}];

ListPlot[approximationPoints, AxesLabel -> {"a0", "b1"}]
```

[image: ListPlot]

```
LinearModelFit[approximationPoints, x, x]["Function"]
```

> `-7.50279*10^-9 + 0.903527 #1 &`

```
fit = Chop[%, 10^-8]
```

> `0 + 0.903527 #1 &`

```
Show[
 ListPlot[approximationPoints, AxesLabel -> {"a0", "b1"}],
 Plot[fit[x], {x, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> Black]]
```

[image: Points&Fit]

```
With[{b2 = -0.01},
 Plot[PDF[pd[#1, #2, b2], x] & @@@ approximationPoints, {x, -100, 100}, 
  PlotRange -> All, Evaluated -> True]]
```

[image: PearsonDistributions]

```
With[{b2 = -0.01},
   percentProfitable[#1, #2, b2] & @@@ approximationPoints
   ] // Round[#, 0.000001] & // DeleteDuplicates
```

> `{0.624954}`

```
With[{b2 = -0.01},
   meanWinLossRatio[#1, #2, b2] & @@@ approximationPoints
   ] // Round[#, 0.0000001] & // DeleteDuplicates
```

> `{0.730939}`

#### 2.3 `PearsonDistribution`s that resemble the given characteristics best

There are now two undetermined parameters, `a0` and `b2`, left. However a look at

```
PDF[PearsonDistribution[a1, a0, b2, b1, b0] /. sol1[[1]] /. b1 -> fit[a0], x] // FullSimplify
```

shows that these only occur as the ratio `a0/b2` and

```
StandardDeviation[
 PearsonDistribution[a1, a0, b2, b1, b0] /. sol1[[1]] /. b1 -> fit[a0]]
```

> `0.253337 Sqrt[a0^2/b2^2]`

reveals that the standard deviation is a function of this ratio.

```
sigmaTransform = 
 Assuming[{σ > 0, b2 < 0}, 
  Simplify@Solve[
    StandardDeviation[
      PearsonDistribution[a1, a0, b2, b1, b0] /. sol1[[1]] /. 
       b1 -> fit[a0]] == σ, a0, Reals]]
```

> `{{a0 -> 3.9473 b2 σ}, {a0 -> -3.9473 b2 σ}}`

Therefore all `PearsonDistribution`s that resemble the given characteristics best can be expressed using

```
pd[σ_ /; σ != 0] = 
 PearsonDistribution[a1, a0, b2, b1, b0] /. sol1[[1]] /. 
    b1 -> fit[a0] /. Last@sigmaTransform /. b2 -> -1
```

> `PearsonDistribution[-7.25873, 3.9473 σ, -1, 3.56649 σ, -4.51175 σ^2]`

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[PDF[pd[s], x], {s, 5, 50, 5}], {x, -100, 100}, 
 PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image: bestPearsonDistributions]

#### 2.4 Tests

```
Through[{Skewness, Kurtosis[#] - 3 &, 
     Function[d, -(Total@#/Length@# &[Select[d, # > 0 &]])/
       (Total@#/Length@# &[Select[d, # < 0 &]])], 
     N@Count[#, dp_ /; dp > 0]/Length[#] &}[RandomVariate[pd[5], #]]] & /@ {10^6, 500}
```

> `{{-2.10828, 11.6199, 0.731186, 0.625318}, {-1.58484, 4.54825, 0.851766, 0.634}}`

```
Through[{Skewness, Kurtosis[#] - 3 &, 
     Function[d, -(Total@#/Length@# &[Select[d, # > 0 &]])/
       (Total@#/Length@# &[Select[d, # < 0 &]])], 
     N@Count[#, dp_ /; dp > 0]/Length[#] &}[RandomVariate[pd[25], #]]] & /@ {10^6, 500}
```

> `{{-2.09863, 11.4751, 0.730866, 0.625946}, {-1.39776, 3.28408, 0.714331, 0.618}}`

#### 2.5 Influence of the weighting

```
With[{b2 = -0.01},
 ParallelTable[
  Through[{percentProfitable[#[[1]], #[[2]], b2] &, 
     meanWinLossRatio[#[[1]], #[[2]], b2] &}[
    NArgMin[
     weight*(percentProfitable[a0, b1, b2] - 0.64)^2/
        0.64 + (meanWinLossRatio[a0, b1, b2] - 0.72)^2/0.72, {a0, b1}]]], 
  {weight, {0.1, 0.5, 1, 2, 5, 7, 10, 100, 1000}}]]
```

> ```
> {{0.618845, 0.721563}, {0.622109, 0.726553}, {0.624954, 0.730939}, {0.628537, 0.736509}, 
>  {0.633264, 0.743943}, {0.634708, 0.746232}, {0.635993, 0.748277}, {0.639515, 0.753919}, 
>  {0.63995, 0.754621}}
> ```

```
ListPlot[%, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: ListPlot]

Answer (score 4):

Following up on @Karsten 7.'s approach, with a more convenient parameterization of `PearsonDistribution` (using pieces from [PearsonDistribution >> Applications](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PearsonDistribution.html)):

```
ClearAll[pearsonD, dis, tdisn, tdisp]
pearsonD[μ_, σ_, γ_, κ_] := PearsonDistribution[2 (9 + 6 γ^2 - 5 κ),
       -12 μ γ^2 - σ γ (3 + κ) + 2 μ (-9 + 5 κ),  6 + 3 γ^2 - 2 κ, -6 μ γ^2 + 
        4 μ (-3 + κ) - σ γ  (3 + κ), 6 μ^2 + 3 (μ^2 + σ^2)  γ^2 - 
        2 (μ^2 + 2 σ^2) κ + μ σ γ  (3 + κ)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Using the provided information on `{μ,  γ, κ} = {.1, -2.1, 15.2}` (Excess Kurtosis is 12.2, hence Kurtosis is 15.2), we get a family of distributions parametrized by `σ`:

```
dis[σ_] := Simplify[pearsonD[.1, σ, -2.1, 15.2]] 

Plot[PDF[pearsonD[.1, #, -2.1, 15.2], x] & /@ {.5, 1, 2, 3} // 
        Evaluate, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotLegends -> ("σ = " <> ToString[#] & /@ {.5, 1, 2, 3})]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[PDF[pearsonD[.1, 2, #, 15.2], x] & /@ {-2, -1, 1, 2} // 
        Evaluate, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotLegends -> ("γ = " <> ToString[#] & /@ {-2, -1, 1, 2})]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[PDF[pearsonD[.1, 2, -2.1, #], x] & /@ {15, 30, 50} // 
        Evaluate, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotLegends -> ("κ = " <> ToString[#] & /@ {15, 30, 50})]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Using the additional information `Mean Win / Mean Loss  == .72`, with a quick-and-dirty graphical approach to find the `σ` that gives a Mean Win / Mean Loss ratio of `.72`:

```
tdisn[σ_] := TruncatedDistribution[{-Infinity, 0}, dis[σ]];
tdisp[σ_] := TruncatedDistribution[{0, Infinity}, dis[σ]];

plt = Plot[Evaluate[-NExpectation[z, Distributed[z, tdisp[s]]]/
                NExpectation[z,  Distributed[z, tdisn[s]]]], {s, .1, 5.}, 
        MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, Mesh -> {{.72}}, 
        MeshStyle -> PointSize[Large], AxesLabel -> {"σ", "win/loss"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Cases[Normal@plt, Point[x_] :> x, Infinity][[1,1]]
```

> 1.80213

Finally, checking the win probability for the resulting distribution, we find that it less than `.64`:

```
NProbability[z >= 0,  Distributed[z, dis[1.80213]]]
```

> 0.617813

```
data = RandomVariate[dis[1.80213], 100000]; 

Through[{Mean, StandardDeviation, Skewness, Kurtosis, 
        Probability[x >= 0, Distributed[ x, #]] &, 
       -NExpectation[Conditioned[x, x >= 0], Distributed[x, #]]/
         NExpectation[Conditioned[x, x <= 0], Distributed[x, #]] &}[
  SmoothKernelDistribution[data]]]
```

> {0.0978247, 1.81193, -2.1395, 15.004, 0.615423, 0.724562}